# How to Import models from 3D software, like Maya into OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, 3d, maya

How can I import 3D models from 3D modelling software like MAYA into OpenGL especially for PC rather than for Iphone development ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing Models Into A OpenGL Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017736/importing-models-into-a-opengl-project)

Comment: Thank you everyone for their contribution ! I have got solution as given by Brad Larson. Many thanks to him...! :) Well, I accept my apology for posting this previously asked question to the forum by mistake. Still everyone who replied here thanks again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe this surprises you, but OpenGL has no such thing qualifying as "models". What OpenGL does is, it accepts a bunch of data and it is upon you to make OpenGL access this data so that the operations it performs on that data will result in a nice image on the screen.

So after that introduction, let's say you got a model, like a cube. A cube consists of 6 faces with 4 corners each. While each corner positions is shared by 3 faces each, the face direction, the so called Normal, is very different on that corner depending which face you're looking at. Position, Normal and a few other attributes form what is known as a vertex. Thus for a cube we have 6 * 4 = 24 vertices (capital position, lower normal)

```
X,   Y,  Z,  x,  y,  z
-1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  0
-1, -1,  1, -1,  0,  0
-1,  1,  1, -1,  0,  0
-1,  1, -1, -1,  0,  0
 1, -1, -1,  1,  0,  0
 1, -1,  1,  1,  0,  0
 1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0
 1,  1, -1,  1,  0,  0
…
```

And so on, I hope you get the idea. Each line forms a *vertex vector*. The format of this vector is arbitrary. You can place those attributes (Position, Normal, etc.) in one common, *interleaved* array, or you use multiple arrays for each attribute in its own array. Interleaved arrays oftenly are more efficient though.

Together with the list of vertices you also have a list of faces, i.e. tuple of vertex indices, which for a face, so in the case of a cube those tuples, designating quadrilaterals would be

```
0, 1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6, 7
...
20, 21, 22, 23
```

Loading a model means, you write some program that reads the data from a model file format (preferably a documented one, or one you came up with yourself and wrote an exporter for your modelling program for). The read data is then placed into memory in such a way as outlined above so that OpenGL can make use of it.

You then supply this data to OpenGL. There are two options: You keep the data in your program's process address space (Client Side Vertex Arrays), or you upload the data into a OpenGL buffer object (Vertex Buffer Object).

Then you tell OpenGL to fetch its geometry data.

In the case of Client Side Vertex Arrays this is done in the following way

```
GLenum primitive_mode;
GLfloat *vertex_data;
GLushort *indices_data;
int face_count;


void load_model(...)
{
    /* ... */
    read_vertex_data_from_file(&vertex_data, 
                               &indices_data, 
                               &face_count, 
                               &primitive_mode, ...);

}

/*...*/

void draw_model()
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(
                    3, /* we're supplying vectors of which the 3 first elements are to be used for vertex position */
                    GL_FLOAT, /* the type of each vector element is GLfloat */
                    sizeof(GLfloat)*6, /* the beginnings of vectors in vertex_data are 6 * sizeof(GLfloat) apart */
                    vertex_data + 0 /* the pointer to the data, positions are offset 0 */
    );

    glNormalPointer( /* normals always have 3 elements, no size given */
                    GL_FLOAT, /* the type of each vector element is GLfloat */
                    sizeof(GLfloat)*6, /* the beginnings of vectors in vertex_data are 6 * sizeof(GLfloat) apart */
                    vertex_data + 3 /* the pointer to the data, normals are offset 3 */
    );

    glDrawElements(primitive_mode, face_count, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices_data);

}
```

It is upon you to either implement the model loader yourself, or use some third party library for this task.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It sounds pretty good to work.

Answer (score 1):

Maya can export to various formats. Nowadays, mainly FBX is used because it's supported by many art packages.

If you're writing an application in c++, there's a FBX Api you can use to read fbx files:
http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=7478532

I think XNA uses this sdk in the background in it's content pipeline. (If you're familiar with xna)

There is also a Python library which can be handy to extract just the data you need from the fbx file: http://download.autodesk.com/us/fbx/20112/FBX_SDK_HELP/files/WS73099cc142f48755-751de9951262947c01c-6dc7.htm

You could also write your own export script in Maya using python, but be aware that this is not a straightforward task.

I'm sure if you google a bit, you'll find importers for other formats like `.obj` which is also commonly used.